# Searching collections in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In my app I have Backbone collection that looks like this:

```
App.Collections.SurveyReportSets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/survey_report_sets',
  model: App.Models.SurveyReportSet,

  byReportType: function(report_type) {
    return this.where({report_type: report_type});
  },

  byReportOrganizationType: function(report_organization_type) {
    return this.where({report_organization_type: report_organization_type});
  }
});
```

This searches works perfectly when I use only one of them. But when I try to use both they not works. Here is how I'm using it:

```
var my_collection = this.collection.byReportType(this.model.get('report_type')).byReportOrganizationType(this.model.get('report_organization_type'))
```

Backbone returns me following error:

```
TypeError: this.collection.byReportType(...).byReportOrganizationType is not a function
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated method to returns collection and it works properly:

```
App.Collections.SurveyReportSets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/survey_report_sets',
  model: App.Models.SurveyReportSet,

  byReportType: function(report_type) {
    return new App.Collections.SurveyReportSets(this.where({report_type: report_type}));
  },

  byReportOrganizationType: function(report_organization_type) {
    return new App.Collections.SurveyReportSets(this.where({report_organization_type: report_organization_type}));
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't suggest doing this. This is invoking the collections constructor and making the cpu do much more work than necessary just for a coding style.

Comment: Just make the methods accept optional parameter (array of models). call the first method, pass the results into the next method. If the optional parameter is not passed, let the method filter the collection itself... you can use `_.where` on the resulting array of models

Answer (score 1):

probably `byReportOrganizationType` fails because `byReportType` returns models which satisfy condition (report type), but it does nto return Backbone.Collection but an array of models. This array obviously doesn't have `byReportOrganizationType` function defined

Comment: So how will be the best way to fix this in backbone?

Comment: sry I missed your question, but apparantly you managed to do it. :)